# How do I limit the number of displayed lines through ls?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

Let's say I have a command

```
ls -Bgclt /somwhere/in/the/past
```

How do I limit the output to show me only first 2 files? (except for having only 2 files in that directory)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simple - you pipe the output through head:

```
ls -Bgclt /somwhere/in/the/past | head -n 3
```

You use -n 3 instead of -n 2 because of the 'total' line at the top of the ls output.

Answer (score 4):

If you are really picky and *only* want to see the name of those two lines (that is, you want to exclude that first line with the word 'total' at the top) you can try

```
ls -Bgclt /somwhere/in/the/past | head -n 3 | tail -n 2
```

Comment: I can exclude it by grep as well.

Comment: @den-javamaniac : True, I was considering that as well.  Only catch is if one of the files you list happen to contain the string you base the grep exclusion on. How likely that is to happen then is another matter.